# WPF folder browser dialog that shows external devices and can navigate to user-given folder path

Tags: c#, wpf, shell, folderbrowserdialog

I have a WPF application where the user must choose a folder for an operation. I achieve this by opening a folder browser dialog when he clicks a button.

I want the dialog to both list external devices, like connected smartphones, and have a textbox where the user can enter a path to a folder and the dialog will be able to navigate to it, like the regular Windows dialogs work.

Currently I have:

```
    FolderItem ShellBrowseForFolder()
    {
        Folder folder = shell.BrowseForFolder(Hwnd, "", 0, 0);
        if (folder != null)
        {
            FolderItem fi = (folder as Folder3).Self;
            return fi;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

which I invoke by:

```
TargetFolderPath = ShellBrowseForFolder()?.Path;
```

This produces a folder browser dialog that looks like this:

[image: Shell folder browser dialog]

This dialog lists external devices but the user can't just type in "C:\some dir" and have the dialog navigate to it.

I've also tried providing options for the `IShellDispatch.BrowseForFolder` method (in accordance with [these listed variants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/ns-shlobj_core-browseinfoa), after reading [the MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/ishelldispatch-browseforfolder)) like so:

```
Folder folder = shell.BrowseForFolder(Hwnd, "", 4, 0);
```

and

```
Folder folder = shell.BrowseForFolder(Hwnd, "", 0x00000004, 0);
```

but I haven't noticed anything changing.

The other dialog I have is:

```
readonly System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowser = new();

if (folderBrowser.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    folderPath = folderBrowser.SelectedPath;
```

This produces dis:

[image: System.Windows.Forms folder browser dialog]

where the user CAN enter a path to a folder BUT this dialog does not show external devices, like connected smartphones.

Is there a way to get the best of both worlds?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Ookii.Dialogs](http://www.ookii.org/software/dialogs/).  Ookii.Dialogs.VistaFolderBrowserDialog should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, even if it isn't an answer to the question, but I'd like my 3rd parties to have been made in this century.

Comment: No worries, though to be fair this was updated 8months ago and supports netcore and .net 5 -> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.   Also seems to do everything you need it too. :-)

Comment: Oh, thanks! I saw the last post on that site was from 2017 and it required .Net Framework 3.5+ so I assumed the guy would at least update his own website.